# android: gridview how to define grid size to always fit in the screen

Tags: android, image, gridview

This is a simple question but i am not able to get the answer.
I want the grid images to resize depending on the device screen.

I have my  Gridview defined as

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#111111">   
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:verticalSpacing="10dip"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:listSelector="@null"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1view"  android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

and in the adapter i am doing :

```
 imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
 // imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`
```

thanks a lot for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    if (activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi > 200) {
       // imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
    }
    else{
       // imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    }

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Comment: Thank you , is there a way we can use some keywords than hardcoding the values in dip

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years later...

To expand slightly on the answer given by fr4n, you could define the image size value in an integer resource xml, then put different values in qualified "values-xxx" resource folders.

e.g. values-mdpi etc.

or if android 3.2 or above

values-sw300dp etc.

> Integer size = getResources().getInteger(R.int.image_size));
>
> imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));

(coded from memory, so no guarantee the syntax is 100% correct)